# Today Extension support for WatchConnectivity?

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension, watchconnectivity

I'd like to display data entered on a watch OS 2 app in a Today Extension without launching the iPhone app first.

Do Today Extensions support sending and receiving date from a watch OS 2 app via the WatchConnectivity framework?

My initial tests were negative, but I am not 100% sure because testing in Xcode and simulator is so unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

No, WatchConnectivity currently only seems to work from the iOS app itself and the WatchKit extension.